# how to evaluate provided words can be spelled using provided letters by ignoring case?

Tags: python, function

```py
words = [
    "Acura", "Ford", "Ferrari", "Honda", "Nissan", "Datsun",
]

letters = [
    "a", "f", "r", "r", "e", "i", "o", "h", "c", "s", "u", "w", "a", "n", "d",  # noqa
]


def can_it_be_spelled():
    """
    Function to determine if the provided word can be spelled using the
    provided letters
      - Evaluation will ignore case
      - Each instance of the provided letters can only be used once
        (e.g. If there aren't enough a's then the word can't be spelled)
    """
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    """
    Instructions:
    Iterate over the provided words and print whether each one
    can be spelled or not using the available letters.  Letters can be reused
    between words, but may only be used once within a word.
    """
    pass
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Looks like homework, what did you try yet ? The easy solution is to make a loop with every word, create a copy of the letters array. For every letters on the word, you check if you can find it in the copy of letters, if you find it, you delete it from the copy array. If you can validate each letter, it can be spelled. This is a rather bad solution, as it can be slow if the number of words to check is high, but the logic should work.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
words = [
    "Acura", "Ford", "Ferrari", "Honda", "Nissan", "Datsun",
]

letters = [
    "a", "f", "r", "r", "e", "i", "o", "h", "c", "s", "u", "w", "a", "n", "d",  # noqa
]


def can_it_be_spelled(word, ls):
    """
    Function to determine if the provided word can be spelled using the
    provided letters
      - Evaluation will ignore case
      - Each instance of the provided letters can only be used once
        (e.g. If there aren't enough a's then the word can't be spelled)
    """
    for l in word.lower():
        if l not in ls: return False
        else: del ls[ls.index(l)] 
    return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    """
    Instructions:
    Iterate over the provided words and print whether each one
    can be spelled or not using the available letters.  Letters can be reused
    between words, but may only be used once within a word.
    """
    for word in words:
        can = '' if can_it_be_spelled(word, letters) else '\'t'
        print(f"{word} can{can} be spelled")
```

Comment: Will not work because a letter can be used once, and not in your solution.

Comment: okay i edited it. does it work now?

Comment: I'll let OP test it, should work i guess.